# Remove nth row in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to remove the nth row of a groupby object, say the last row. I can extract this row using `groupby.nth`

Is there a similar method to remove the nth row, or equivalently get all the rows except the nth row?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find index of all [`nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) rows and then select [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'B':[4,5,6,7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B
0  1  4
1  1  5
2  1  6
3  2  7
4  2  8
5  2  9

print (df.ix[df.index.difference(df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].nth(1).index)])
   A  B
0  1  4
2  1  6
3  2  7
5  2  9
```

```
idx = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].nth(1).index
print (idx)
Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')

print (df.index.difference(idx))
Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 5], dtype='int64')

print (df.ix[df.index.difference(idx)])
   A  B
0  1  4
2  1  6
3  2  7
5  2  9
```

If need all rows without last, use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
print (df.ix[df.index.difference(df.groupby('A')['B'].tail(1).index)])

   A  B
0  1  4
1  1  5
3  2  7
4  2  8
```

---

**Timings**:

```
In [27]: %timeit (df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1, :]).reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit (df.ix[df.index.difference(df.groupby('A')['B'].tail(1).index)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit (df.ix[df.index.difference(df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].nth(1).index)])
The slowest run took 4.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `df` is your dataframe.

```
df.groupby(something_to_group_by).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1, :]).reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index()
```